# KeyError generated when editing site setting with foreign key set

Tags: wagtail

**Django Version:** 2.1.5

**Python Version:** 3.6.8

**Wagtail Version:** 2.4

I have a template with four columns of links in the footer.  I have set up the following models which consist of a `BaseSetting` object and footer link objects for each column of links.  The footer link objects each `ForeignKey` to the `TemplateItems` object.

```
@register_setting
class TemplateItems(BaseSetting):
    page_banner = models.OneToOneField('wagtailimages.Image', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+',  help_text='Banner image that shows below menu on pages other than home page')
    footer_link_col1_header = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='', verbose_name='Footer Link Column 1 Header')
    footer_link_col2_header = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, default='', verbose_name='Footer Link Column 2 Header')
    footer_link_col3_header = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, default='', verbose_name='Footer Link Column 3 Header')
    footer_link_col4_header = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, default='', verbose_name='Footer Link Column 4 Header')

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('page_banner'),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('footer_link_col1_header'),
            InlinePanel('footer_links_col_1', label='Column 1 Links'),
            FieldPanel('footer_link_col2_header'),
            InlinePanel('footer_links_col_2', label='Column 2 Links'),
            FieldPanel('footer_link_col3_header'),
            InlinePanel('footer_links_col_3', label='Column 3 Links'),
            FieldPanel('footer_link_col4_header'),
            InlinePanel('footer_links_col_4', label='Column 4 Links'),
        ], heading='Footer Links'),
        InlinePanel('social_media_links', label="Social Media Links"),
    ]


class FooterLink(Orderable):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')

    panels = [
        FieldRowPanel([
            FieldPanel('name'),
            FieldPanel('url'),
        ])
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class FooterLinkCol1(FooterLink):
    template_items = ForeignKey('TemplateItems', related_name='footer_links_col_1', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class FooterLinkCol2(FooterLink):
    template_items = ForeignKey('TemplateItems', related_name='footer_links_col_2', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class FooterLinkCol3(FooterLink):
    template_items = ForeignKey('TemplateItems', related_name='footer_links_col_3', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class FooterLinkCol4(FooterLink):
    template_items = ForeignKey('TemplateItems', related_name='footer_links_col_4', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Migrations are created and migrated successfully, but when I go to the `TemplateItems` settings object in the Wagtail admin in order to add footer links, I receive the following error:

> KeyError at /admin/settings/main/templateitems/2/
>
> 'footer_links_col_1'

If I comment out any of the footer_links_col_X items, then I receive the error for the first one that is not commented out.  There are no existing footer links in the database for any of the columns.  I wondered if the problem was coming because the `ForeignKey` is to a `BaseSetting` object, but when I declare these models in the Django admin (including the inlines for each of the column links), it displays and allows me to add links just fine.

Traceback:

> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py"
>   in _wrapped_view_func
>     44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/**init**.py"
>   in wrapper
>     102.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/decorators.py"
>   in decorated_view
>     34.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/settings/views.py"
>   in edit
>     83.             instance=instance, form=form, request=request)
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py"
>   in bind_to_instance
>     153.         new.on_instance_bound()
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py"
>   in on_instance_bound
>     295.                                                    request=self.request))
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py"
>   in bind_to_instance
>     153.         new.on_instance_bound()
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py"
>   in on_instance_bound
>     295.                                                    request=self.request))
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py"
>   in bind_to_instance
>     153.         new.on_instance_bound()
>
> File
>   "/opt/virtualenvs/MY_SITE-a0hNfZxl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py"
>   in on_instance_bound
>     692.         self.formset = self.form.formsets[self.relation_name]
>
> Exception Type: KeyError at /admin/settings/main/templateitems/2/
>   Exception Value: 'footer_links_col_1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InlinePanel requires the corresponding foreign key to be a `ParentalKey`:

```
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey

class FooterLinkCol1(FooterLink):
    template_items = ParentalKey('TemplateItems', related_name='footer_links_col_1', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

In turn, ParentalKey requires the parent model to inherit from `ClusterableModel` (which is automatically true for Wagtail `Page` models):

```
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel

class TemplateItems(BaseSetting, ClusterableModel):
```

(There's some explanation of the motivation for ClusterableModel / ParentalKey in [the readme for django-modelcluster](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster/blob/master/README.rst).)